Can't connect binaries to internal modules defined through lib
So I am trying to get my binaries to work while allowing them to reference mods declared in the lib.rs file, only I can't get them to work.
My cargo file:
[package]
name = "mytestapp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[features]
mainnet = []
testnet = []

[[bin]]
name = "file1"
path = "src/standalone_tools/file1.rs"
[[bin]]
name = "file2"
path = "src/standalone_tools/file2.rs"
[[bin]]
name = "file3"
path = "src/standalone_tools/file3.rs"

[dependencies]
sha2 = "0.10"

My lib.rs
pub mod standalone_tools;

My main.rs
use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod1;
use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod2;
use mytestapp::standalone_tools::nod3;

main{
// stuff
}

Without the [[bin]] directives and files in the cargo, this will compile up to this point without errors.
My src/standalone_tools/file1.rs
use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod1;
use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod2;
use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod3;

main{
// stuff
}

the file2 and file3 pretty much do the same thing.
This creates an error when using cargo build --features "mainnet"
All the src/standalone_tools/ files, end up erroring saying:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `mytestapp`

If instead of use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod1; I use use crate::standalone_tools::mod1;
the errors will change to
2 | use crate::standalone_tools::mod1;
  |            ^^^^^^^
  |            |
  |            unresolved import
  |            help: a similar path exists: `mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod1`

So none of my binaries compile.
If I remove all the [[bin]] declarations from the cargo file, the app will compile just fine, so using use mytestapp::standalone_tools::mod1; for example, works from the main.rs and compiles perfectly.
So why can't the binaries in src/standalone_tools find it? How do I make it so I can compile the binaries without having to restructure each binary into its own folder with its own cargo file? What I am doing wrong when trying to import the modules to the binaries?

Tip: If you rename standalone_tools to bin your [[bin]] definitions are the default and thus can be removed. (that's unrelated to your problem though)

pub mod standalone_tools; in lib.rs is most definitely not what you want. If you need functionality in both src/main.rs and src/standalone_tools/file1.rs it should be defined in lib.rs (or a submodule) and imported with use mytestapp::the::shared::thing; in both src/standalone_tools/file1.rs and src/main.rs

Isn't that literally what lib.rs is for... declaring mods in the library that can then be referenced from package_name::module instead of crate::module? (aside from it being for declaring mods from for a lib) As my app is both library and binary in the same package.

The problem is that src/standalone_tools/*.rs are both treated as binary crate and simultaneously as an unrelated (apart from sharing the same source) module the way you've defined them. You pretty much always want either of them, not both.

I am kind of gathering you are saying... I have to restructure each binary to its own directory with its own cargo if I want to share libraries... cause the thing is, my question dumbed it down, we are talking a few hundred files in the standalone_tools, some of which are modules to connect to servers and the likes (its a client/server app I am working on). So I kind of need the mods from that folder as well as the rest mods one level up.

The short version: Every file should either be a binary crate, (exclusive-)or included via a single mod statement.
